# Fonts set in CSS fail to change when webpage is run

Tags: css

I am a beginner coder and i have a small problem.I set the font types of my paragraph and heading in my HTML document to Arial using CSS. the code is as follows

```
h4{
font-family 
arial san-serif;
}
```

The problem is that when I run the code the font doesn't change.

firstly I would like to know why this is. Could it possibly mean that I don't have the font on my computer. If so how do I correct this. Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. It might be worth it to know that I am running notepad ++

Comment: It should be h4{ font-family: arial sans-serif; }

Answer (score 0):

```
font-family:
```

you forgot ":"

```
 h4{ 
      font-family: arial, san-serif;
 }
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a colon `:` and a comma `,`.

```
h4{
    font-family: arial, san-serif; 
}
```

Also keep in mind that if you are using fonts with spaces, quote them.

```
h4 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

[W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp) has a good explanation if you want to read more about it.